# Is it normal to get some request timed out in tracert?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, isp, traceroute

I was wondering if it's normal to have some request timed out in tracert.

For example:

```
C:\>tracert www.google.com

Tracing route to www.google.com [216.58.210.36]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    10 ms     5 ms     5 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out. <--
  3     *       70 ms    65 ms  31.55.185.181
  4    76 ms    60 ms   101 ms  31.55.185.188
  5    64 ms    69 ms    64 ms  core2-hu0-12-0-3.colindale.ukcore.bt.net [195.99.127.120]
  6    49 ms    42 ms    50 ms  peer2-et-3-0-4.slough.ukcore.bt.net [109.159.252.122]
  7   111 ms   122 ms   100 ms  109.159.253.69
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out. <--
  9    61 ms    58 ms    57 ms  108.170.238.116
 10    97 ms    93 ms    96 ms  108.170.232.103
 11   174 ms   150 ms   122 ms  lhr25s11-in-f4.1e100.net [216.58.210.36]

Trace complete.
```

```
C:\>tracert 1.1.1.1

Tracing route to one.one.one.one [1.1.1.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    21 ms     7 ms    10 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.  <-- 
  3     *       65 ms    54 ms  31.55.185.181
  4   103 ms   101 ms   102 ms  31.55.185.188
  5    50 ms    57 ms    65 ms  core1-hu0-15-0-7.colindale.ukcore.bt.net [213.121.192.10]
  6    61 ms    62 ms    63 ms  peer7-et-3-1-1.telehouse.ukcore.bt.net [109.159.252.164]
  7   150 ms   147 ms   214 ms  109.159.253.95
  8    88 ms    64 ms    73 ms  one.one.one.one [1.1.1.1]

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Completely normal... It just means a device at that network hop is not responding to a ping request. If that happens consistently, then it it can be ignored as it means the device is configured that way. If that happens only once in a while it is often a sign of equipment at or exceeding it's load capacity (ie. it doesn't have time to respond to a ping request), or the some other issues.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is quite normal. It is an indicator that the device your using does not have have enough capacity to respond, or is configured to ignore (or not respond to) pings.